# Could I make my own USB Type A/A cable?

Tags: usb, cable

Can I

- take two USB 2.0 cables,
- take the end that doesn't plug into the computer (the "receptacle" or "Type B" one),
- cut it off,
- then re-attach the two cables,

so I can plug both ends to my computer?

The reason why I'm looking to do this, is because I have an eBook reader that requires a PC sync through USB, and its USB receptacle is exact same port found on all computers.

To clarify, the ends I need look like this:

[image: male A]

And I'm looking to make a cable that has just this kind of plug.  Like this: [image: male A to male A USB cable]

Comment: you could probably find one off the shelf - many USB HDDs used to use that sort of cable

Comment: So your eBook reader has a full Type A receptacle? How do they expect you to sync with that?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much any computer retailer will stock these cables. Dirt cheap too. You can order off new egg too: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812270158

Comment: Why not just buy one [Amazon UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/1-8M-USB-Data-Cable-Male/dp/B001J0TYCK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1313755732&sr=8-1) / [Amazon US](http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-6-Feet-Beige-USB-Cable/dp/B0002MKBI2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1313755774&sr=8-1)

Comment: @slhck Yes it does.  It's a bit old, just got it from my grandfather (he didn't think it worked... I changed the batteries...).  I can't find a top view on the web, but the he optional docking cradle looks like [this].(http://salestores.com/stores/images/images_747/EUC1.jpg)

Comment: I assume you're asking because you happen to have a lot of spare USB cables around that aren't the right type for your eBook Reader (if not and you're thinking of buying two new cables... don't, just buy a proper one like what's been mentioned in the comments.) In theory it'd be easy, as it's usually just four wires inside the cable... however I'm not sure if the pinout changes when changing from a type B/mini/whatever other connector that you're chopping off. Do a bit of research, but again it's just a lot easier (and guaranteed to work) if you buy one pre-made.

Comment: @windos Thanks for the advice, but I really want to try making my own... I've already started... wish me luck!

Comment: If someone posts an answer, I'll mark it as correct....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. there's no reason you can't connect the two cable ends. It's probably not worth the effort, though, because you can order this kind of cable online for very little.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can even buy this on any online shop, simply search for father-father usb cable or similar.

But: the devices are communicating on usb on a *master-slave protocol*, and in most cases, master is a mother connector and the slaves are fathers. (Although it is quite possible to construct devices working on other ways).

So, although you can do this, it is highly probable that you won't be able to do anything with it.

Once in my life I've meet such a cable. It was used as a peer-to-peer usb network cable: plugging the both ends into the usb slots of 2 machines, it created a peer-to-peer ethernet over usb link. But in this cable, there were "something" (i.e. some active electronics) on the half of the cable.

You can also build your own devices around it, or it could be usable to solve some complex usb configurations (which are unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

You can (fairly easily) splice your own because there are only four wires (plus a ground), however you should beware of signal issues such as [ingress and egress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egress_%28signal_leakage%29). It probably won’t be an issue for your application, but if you are going to transfer data at high speeds or have sources of electro-magnetic noise near the cable, it could cause some problems (at best, lower speeds, at worst, data corruption).

As others have pointed out, you can get a ready-made (and presumably/questionably more reliable) gender-changer online for next to nothing. Your best bet is [eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_sop=15&_nkw=usb%20male%20-female%20-b%20-mini%20-dip%20-5%20-jack%20-firewire), where you can find a cable for